# Сколько памяти занимает текст в таблице `Oracle`?

Tags: oracle

Есть поле `nvarchar2` в таблице, в котором записано 63 символа.
В другой таблице есть `nclob` в котором записано 829 символов.

Сколько памяти занимает эти 63 и 829 символов?

Comment: Кодировка базы (или колонок) какая. там в кодировке явно указано количетво бит на имвол. сейчас например распространена UTF8AL16 -  16 бит, т.е. 2 байта на символ

Comment: Что понимается под памятью, место на диске?

Comment: кодировка `AL32UTF8`, Да, сколько места на диске занимает данное количество символов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поля с типом **N**VARCHAR2 и **N**CLOB могут быть только в кодировках AL16UTF16 или в UTF8. По умолчанию используется AL16UTF16, определяется на уровне базы данных. Узнать установленную:

```
select * from nls_database_parameters where PARAMETER='NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET'
```

Один символ в кодировке AL16UTF16 занимает до 4-х байт. Соответственно, получается, что ваши сроки занимают **до** 63*4 и 829*4, в зависимости от набора символов.

Сколько конкретно байтов занимает значение в колонке с типом NVARCHAR2 (не NCLOB) можно узнать использую функцию LENGTH**B**(*column*).

Для NCLOB все сложнее, можно **попробовать** (могу ошибаться) считать размер в байтах по 4000 символов: `LENGTHB(dbms_lob.substr(<NCLOB-Column>,1,4000))`.
Тут меня несколько смущает преобразование кодировок из NATIONAL_CHARACTER_SET в CHARACTER_SET, я бы сильно не рассчитывал на такое преобразование.

Еще можно попробовать NCLOB преобразовать в BLOB (использую `dbms_lob.converttoblob`), а потом вызвать `dbms_lob.getlength`.

Ну или чтобы совсем точно, то можно найти номер дата-файла и блока (использую `dbms_rowid.rowid_relative_fno(ROWID)`, `dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(ROWID)`), сделать дамп (`alter system dump datafile <номер дата-файла> block <номер блока>`) и посмотреть в каталоге `USER_DUMP_DEST` файл трассировки. Этот способ будет работать для любых типов.